# Why is log4Net not logging to Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle11g, log4net, log4net-configuration

I am using OracleAppender to log messages in Oracle 11g table. But it is not logging anything there. I am also using EventLogAppender and RollingFileAppender which are working fine and logging messages. But OracleAppender is not working. The log4Net config section for Oracle appender looks like this:

```
  <connectionType value="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.113.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  <connectionString value="DATA SOURCE= servername:portname/DBNAME; USER ID= user-id; PASSWORD= password;" />  
  <!--Below is the hardcoded insert for testing purpose-->
  <commandText value="Insert into MSG_LOG  (LOG_ID, COMPONENT_NAME, LOG_DETAILS, LOG_PARAMETER_LIST, LOG_TYPE, REQUEST_ID, QUEUE_ID, OTHER_ID, LOG_USER_ID, LOG_DATE)
                         VALUES (335, '', '', '', 'test', '','', '', 'test', NULL)" />
```

I am struggling with this for quite some time now, so thought of asking. Are you able to see any obvious problem that I am probably blind to see?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this post is kind of old, but I'd just like to add an account of my own experience here, should someone else stumble upon it in the future.

None of the solutions suggested by any Google searches solved the problem for me. So I decided to download the log4net source code and added the project to my solution which would allow me to step through the code.

At some point the AdoNetAppender evaluates it's buffer property, and there was a comment right above that read (paraphrased), "...if the buffer is 1, log immediately...". So I checked my own buffer size and it had a value of 100. Changing the value to 1 solved the problem for me.

Furthermore, according to the [log4net documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.BufferingAppenderSkeleton.BufferSize.html) the default value is 512, and seeing as your buffer size was not explicitly set, as per your sample configuration in you question, it might be defaulting.

Hope this helps!

TL;DR: Set AdoNetAppender buffer size to 1 as follows:

```
<appender name="DBAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
   <bufferSize value="1"/>
   <!-- rest of configuration... -->
</appender>
```

Answer (score 5):

You should enable internal log4net logging to see what is wrong, enable log4net logging from the FAQ:

> There are 2 different ways to enable internal debugging in log4net.
>   These are listed below. The preferred method is to specify the
>   log4net.Internal.Debug option in the application's config file.
>
> • Internal debugging can also be enabled by setting a value in the
>   application's configuration file (not the log4net configuration file,
>   unless the log4net config data is embedded in the application's config
>   file). The log4net.Internal.Debug application setting must be set to
>   the value true. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

> This setting is read immediately on startup an will cause all internal
>   debugging messages to be emitted.
>
> • To enable log4net's internal debug programmatically you need to set
>   the log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging property to true. Obviously
>   the sooner this is set the more debug will be produced.
>
> Internal debugging messages are written to the console and to the
>   System.Diagnostics.Trace system. If the application does not have a
>   console the messages logged there will be lost. Note that an
>   application can redirect the console stream by setting the
>   System.Console.Out. The Trace system will by default send the message
>   to an attached debugger (where the messages will appear in the output
>   window). If the process does not have a debugger attached then the
>   messages are sent to the system debugger. A utility like DebugView
>   from http://www.sysinternals.com may be used to capture these
>   messages.
>
> As log4net internal debug messages are written to the
>   System.Diagnostics.Trace system it is possible to redirect those
>   messages to a local file. You can define a trace listener by adding
>   the following to your application's .config file:

```
<configuration>
    ...

    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true">
            <listeners>
                <add 
                    name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                    type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                    initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>

    ...
</configuration>
```

> Make sure that the process running your application has permission to
>   write to this file.

Answer (score 0):

The buffer size flushes the inserts to disk and commits.  Otherwise there is latency and messages won't appear immediately depending on logging frequency